# Rows with a variable number of columns?

Tags: mysql, database-design, varchar

I'm trying to design a database for a program that is storing and manipulating tweets off of Twitter.

I'm using code to fragment a tweet into words, usernames, and hashtags, so

```
I'm meeting @President over coffee to talk about my new job #cabinet #woot
```

would break down into `{meeting, over, coffee, talk, about, new, job}` (getting rid of words under 2 letters and after stripping punctuation), `{president}`, and `{cabinet,woot}`.

With my lack of experience in this area, I'd like to just be able to grow the number of rows in a column as necessary, but my intuition tells me that this would be a nightmare.  Another possibility I've considered is just picking an arbitrary number like 10 columns to store words, 5 for usernames, etc., but this would be roughing it a bit, as I don't know for sure how many there will be, and I'd have to throw out what may be valuable information.

As it stands now, I have 3 `varchar`s of sufficient length which hold "meeting over coffee talk about new job", "president", and "cabinet woot".  So, whenever I need to grab the information for a particular tweet, I retrieve the row and break up the strings.

Is this the "correct" route?  Am I missing an obvious way that will make my life easier? (I had found something online about using `array`, but I'm using MySQL and it doesn't seem to support that datatype.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edited after a couple of comments by the question asker!:

Better idea for your design: [image: new sample schema]

(If you're not familar with these diagrams, that's seven tables, with foreign key links as pictured [the three `_Link` tables all have two foreign keys referencing the data tables]. It probably looks like I'm overcomplicating things, but trust me, "tokenise once and store in the database" is *so* much more efficient than "tokenise data each time you retrieve it".)

Sample data, using a simple tweet (ignoring Users for now, it's the same concept though): "test tweet! #howdoesthiswork #newbie"

```
      Tweet
TweetID   WordCount
   1         2

Tweet_Word_Link
TweetID   WordID
   1         1
   1         2

      Word
WordID    Word
   1      test
   2      tweet

Tweet_Hashtag_Link
TweetID  HashtagID
   1         1
   1         2

      Hashtag
HashtagID  Hashtag
    1      #howdoesthiswork
    2      #newbie
```

This allows you to easily get all the users linked in a tweet:

```
SELECT U.UserName
FROM  User U
        INNER JOIN
      Tweet_User_Link TUL ON U.UserID = TUL.UserID
        INNER JOIN
      Tweet T ON TUL.TweetID = T.TweetID
WHERE T.TweetID = <your ID here>
```

(change table names as appropriate for Hashtags and Words)

Or, slightly more complicated, get the top 10 words for all tweets mentioning a specific hashtag:

```
SELECT TOP 10 W.Word, COUNT(*) AS WordCount
FROM  Word W
        INNER JOIN
      Tweet_Word_Link TWL ON TWL.WordID = W.WordID
        INNER JOIN
      Tweet T ON TWL.TweetID = T.TweetID
        INNER JOIN
      Tweet_Hashtag_Link THL ON THL.TweetID = T.TweetID
        INNER JOIN
      Hashtag H ON H.HashtagID = THL.HashtagID
WHERE H.Hashtag = <your hashtag here>
GROUP By W.Word
```

(I've used ANSI SQL syntax, I'm not 100% sure if MySQL supports all of ANSI SQL - but it should be close enough.)